# How to do eager initialization of singleton in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, initialization, guice, eager-loading

I would like to do eager initialization of multiple singletons but the initialization can take on the order of minutes so I would like the initialization to happen on a separate thread.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you use proxies of these singletons? do you want to parallelize the init of these expensive singletons within the wiring phase only?

Comment: If you have multiple singletons which take minutes to initialise it sounds like you have design problem. You should always be able to write an application so it doesn't take minutes to start.  Perhaps you could explain why it takes so long, perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

http://tembrel.blogspot.com/2009/11/concurrently-initialized-singletons-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just start an auxiliary Thread and let it do it. The easiest way is using [SingletonHolder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh) and doing anything which causes the initialization in the auxiliary Thread. Other threads will block if they try to access it before the initialization finishes, so everything works fine.

Comment: That's lazy, not eager, initialization.

Comment: Did you really read my answer? SingletonHolder means lazy initialization, accessing it immediately in a new thread makes it happen ASAP. This is about all what can be achieved, isn't it? --- I see now you tagged your question with guice, this changes things.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made the Guice part more obvious in the question.